# How do I deserialize an XML API response in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, api, deserialization

I am working on a project that calls an API (using C# ASP.NET), and the API returns an XML document. I know how to deserialize an response in JSON, but am running into issues with deserializing an XML response. Currently I am getting the below error when attempting to deserialize the XML:

> InvalidOperationException: response xmlns="" was not expected.

The error code displayed just the empty quotes in the error message. I have the code samples below, and I would greatly appreciate any constructive feedback or advice on making this better, and any advice on where I went wrong on attempting to deserialize this!

Here is the XML response from the API call (This API only returns either CML or a .csv):

```
<response xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.2" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.aviationweather.gov/static/adds/schema/metar1_2.xsd">
<request_index>554967903</request_index>
<data_source name="metars"/>
<request type="retrieve"/>
<errors/>
<warnings/>
<time_taken_ms>7</time_taken_ms>
<data num_results="3">

<METAR>
    <raw_text>KDEN 102353Z 15007KT 10SM FEW220 07/M08 A3038 RMK AO2 SLP285 T00721083 10133 20072 58015</raw_text>
    <station_id>KDEN</station_id>
    <observation_time>2022-01-10T23:53:00Z</observation_time> 
    <latitude>39.85</latitude>
    <longitude>-104.65</longitude>
    <temp_c>7.2</temp_c>
    <dewpoint_c>-8.3</dewpoint_c>
    <wind_dir_degrees>150</wind_dir_degrees>
    <wind_speed_kt>7</wind_speed_kt> 
    <visibility_statute_mi>10.0</visibility_statute_mi>
    <altim_in_hg>30.380905</altim_in_hg>
    <sea_level_pressure_mb>1028.5</sea_level_pressure_mb>
    <quality_control_flags>
        <auto_station>TRUE</auto_station>
    </quality_control_flags>
    <sky_condition sky_cover="FEW" cloud_base_ft_agl="22000"/>
    <flight_category>VFR</flight_category>
    <three_hr_pressure_tendency_mb>-1.5</three_hr_pressure_tendency_mb>
    <maxT_c>13.3</maxT_c>
    <minT_c>7.2</minT_c>
    <metar_type>METAR</metar_type>
    <elevation_m>1656.0</elevation_m>
</METAR>
<METAR>
    <raw_text>KSEA 102353Z 34003KT 6SM -RA BR FEW015 BKN035 OVC045 08/06 A3035 RMK AO2 SLP288 P0000 60001 T00780056 10083 20044 50003</raw_text>
   <station_id>KSEA</station_id>   
   <observation_time>2022-01-10T23:53:00Z</observation_time>
   <latitude>47.45</latitude>
     <longitude>-122.32</longitude>
    <temp_c>7.8</temp_c>
    <dewpoint_c>5.6</dewpoint_c>
    <wind_dir_degrees>340</wind_dir_degrees>
    <wind_speed_kt>3</wind_speed_kt>
    <visibility_statute_mi>6.0</visibility_statute_mi>
    <altim_in_hg>30.351377</altim_in_hg>
    <sea_level_pressure_mb>1028.8</sea_level_pressure_mb>
    <quality_control_flags>
         <auto_station>TRUE</auto_station>
    </quality_control_flags>
    <wx_string>-RA BR</wx_string>
    <sky_condition sky_cover="FEW" cloud_base_ft_agl="1500"/>
    <sky_condition sky_cover="BKN" cloud_base_ft_agl="3500"/>
    <sky_condition sky_cover="OVC" cloud_base_ft_agl="4500"/>
    <flight_category>VFR</flight_category>
    <three_hr_pressure_tendency_mb>0.3</three_hr_pressure_tendency_mb>
    <maxT_c>8.3</maxT_c>
    <minT_c>4.4</minT_c>
    <precip_in>0.005</precip_in>
    <pcp6hr_in>0.01</pcp6hr_in>
    <metar_type>METAR</metar_type>
    <elevation_m>115.0</elevation_m>
</METAR>
<METAR>
    <raw_text>PHNL 102353Z 19009KT 10SM FEW025 FEW035 SCT050 26/21 A2997 RMK AO2 SLP147 T02560206 10261 20200 58017</raw_text>
    <station_id>PHNL</station_id>
    <observation_time>2022-01-10T23:53:00Z</observation_time>
    <latitude>21.33</latitude>
    <longitude>-157.93</longitude>
    <temp_c>25.6</temp_c>
    <dewpoint_c>20.6</dewpoint_c>
    <wind_dir_degrees>190</wind_dir_degrees>
    <wind_speed_kt>9</wind_speed_kt>
    <visibility_statute_mi>10.0</visibility_statute_mi>
    <altim_in_hg>29.970472</altim_in_hg>
    <sea_level_pressure_mb>1014.7</sea_level_pressure_mb>
    <quality_control_flags>
         <auto_station>TRUE</auto_station>
    </quality_control_flags>
    <sky_condition sky_cover="FEW" cloud_base_ft_agl="2500"/>
    <sky_condition sky_cover="FEW" cloud_base_ft_agl="3500"/>
    <sky_condition sky_cover="SCT" cloud_base_ft_agl="5000"/>
    <flight_category>VFR</flight_category>
    <three_hr_pressure_tendency_mb>-1.7</three_hr_pressure_tendency_mb>
    <maxT_c>26.1</maxT_c>
    <minT_c>20.0</minT_c>
    <metar_type>METAR</metar_type>
    <elevation_m>2.0</elevation_m>
</METAR>
</data>
</response>
```

This is the code to call the API:

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            string baseUrl = "https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&stationString=KMSP&hoursBeforeNow=2";
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
            HttpResponseMessage result = client.GetAsync(baseUrl).Result;
            XmlSerializer serialObject = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MetarReport));

            List<MetarReport> MetarCollection = new List<MetarReport>();
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                using (Stream reader = result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result)
                {
                    MetarReport metar = new MetarReport();
                    metar = (MetarReport)serialObject.Deserialize(reader);
                    MetarCollection.Add(metar);
                }
            }
            // Test deserializer
            foreach(var item in MetarCollection)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.rawText);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

And this is the object I am attempting to deserialize the XML into

```
[XmlRoot("METAR")]
    [XmlType("METAR")]
    public class MetarReport
    {
        [XmlElement("raw_text")]
        public string rawText { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("station_id")]
        public string stationId { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("latitude")]
        public double latitiude { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("longitude")]
        public double longitude { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("temp_c")]
        public double tempCelsius { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("dewpoint_c")]
        public double dewpoint { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("wind_dir_degree")]
        public int windDirection { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("wind_speed_kt")]
        public double windspeed { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("visibility_statute_mi")]
        public double visbilityMiles { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("altim_in_hg")]
        public double altimeter { get; set; }
        //[XmlElement("sky_condition")]
        //public List<SkyCondition> skyConditions {get; set;}
        [XmlElement("flight_category")]
        public string flightCategory { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("metar_type")]
        public string metarType { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("elevation_m")]
        public double elevationMeters { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Separate issue, but why are you blocking with . Result instead of awaiting the async calls?

Comment: The way I interpret [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/controlling-xml-serialization-using-attributes#controlling-serialization-of-classes-using-xmlrootattribute-and-xmltypeattribute), the root element has to be the actual root of the xml, not the element you would like to begin reading from.

Comment: This is my first forray into working with API's (and XML)  and I am blocking with Result from following another Stackoverflow question.

Comment: That's the blessing and curse of SO

Comment: Changed the [XmlRoot()] attribute to the <response> root element and it made it past the error now, but gets hung up without an error when the Deserializer is called.

Comment: @Crowcoder - truer words never spoken about SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, it was tested in Visual Studio

```
    HttpResponseMessage response= client.GetAsync(baseUrl).Result;

     string xml;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        xml =  response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }   

   Response result;

     XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response));
  
     using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
     {
        result = (Response)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
     }
```

classes

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "response")]
public class Response
{

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "request_index")]
    public int RequestIndex { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "data_source")]
    public DataSource DataSource { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "request")]
    public Request Request { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "errors")]
    public object Errors { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "warnings")]
    public object Warnings { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "time_taken_ms")]
    public int TimeTakenMs { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "data")]
    public Data Data { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsd")]
    public string Xsd { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi")]
    public string Xsi { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "noNamespaceSchemaLocation")]
    public string NoNamespaceSchemaLocation { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "quality_control_flags")]
public class QualityControlFlags
{

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "auto_station")]
    public string AutoStation { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "sky_condition")]
public class SkyCondition
{

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "sky_cover")]
    public string SkyCover { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "cloud_base_ft_agl")]
    public int CloudBaseFtAgl { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "METAR")]
public class METAR
{

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sky_condition")]
    public List<SkyCondition> SkyCondition { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "flight_category")]
    public string FlightCategory { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "three_hr_pressure_tendency_mb")]
    public double ThreeHrPressureTendencyMb { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "maxT_c")]
    public decimal MaxTC { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "minT_c")]
    public decimal MinTC { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "precip_in")]
    public double PrecipIn { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "pcp6hr_in")]
    public double Pcp6hrIn { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "metar_type")]
    public string MetarType { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "elevation_m")]
    public double ElevationM { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "raw_text")]
    public string RawText { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "station_id")]
    public string StationId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "observation_time")]
    public DateTime ObservationTime { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "latitude")]
    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "longitude")]
    public double Longitude { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "temp_c")]
    public double TempC { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "dewpoint_c")]
    public double DewpointC { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "wind_dir_degrees")]
    public int WindDirDegrees { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "wind_speed_kt")]
    public int WindSpeedKt { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "visibility_statute_mi")]
    public double VisibilityStatuteMi { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "altim_in_hg")]
    public double AltimInHg { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sea_level_pressure_mb")]
    public decimal SeaLevelPressureMb { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "quality_control_flags")]
    public QualityControlFlags QualityControlFlags { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "data")]
public class Data
{

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "METAR")]
    public List<METAR> METAR { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "num_results")]
    public int NumResults { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "data_source")]
public class DataSource
{

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "request")]
public class Request
{

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This worked just as expected! Thanks for the help - I see what I did wrong now. Each of the root elements needs it's own class to deserialize properly - not just the element I was targeting. Lesson learned!